# VHDL assert: set category for modelsim message viewer

Tags: vhdl, modelsim

When I write assertions in vhdl, they are displayd in ModelSim in the message viewer with the category "Misc".

Is there a way to set the category of the assertion, so they are sorted as seen in the following graphic (Figure 2-85), where the assertions are sorted in Groups (Misc, SDF, TimingChecks)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VHDL, up to 1076-2002 understands only severity levels for classifying assertions:

type SEVERITY_LEVEL is (NOTE, WARNING, ERROR, FAILURE);

And all those fall inside category Misc in Modelsim's Message Viewer during simulations.

A workaround is to prefix the report string with the Group name you require: Misc, SDF, TimingChecks, etc.
And then, after simulation, go to Message Viewer and sort by "Message" column by clicking on it.